# leaving old job

Tags: job-change

My husband has worked nearly 4 years for this company.  He wants to change jobs.  He went to an interview, and was accepted for a new job since he had the answer.  He and gave his letter to leave with a week's notice time, giving for his company time to get someone else in his place.

The new job has training beginning on 18 November and work starting on 27 November.

His old company told him that he had to stay a month before leaving. Is it true that he has to give a month's notice to his old company?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Comment: Leaving in one week is a bit abrupt.  It isn't clear what profession this is, so it's hard to tell - for software and engineering companies this would be a serious hit. If he's bussing tables they'll probably muddle through.

Answer (score 3):

This is contract law so your husband will have to look into his contract. Generally speaking, in most countries you have a so called notice-period. You cannot just leave the next day, you need to give notice and then you are free to leave a specified time later. In some countries that is handled by general law, some only have it in the contract, the period itself varies from country to country as well. Again, look into the contract and if you are unsure, get a lawyer.